# Yet another mod_rewrite problem

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get mod_rewrite running for one of my PHP project. Unfortunately it doesn't work, I always get 404 errors. My URLs look like this:
`http://admin.domain.com/index.php?page=#1&action=#2`
I'd like to rewrite this to the above URL:
`http://admin.domain.com/#1/#2/`

There are some special cases like when there's no action or additional parameters are specified.

Here's my virtualhost config (**edited**):

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName admin.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory "/var/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /awstats/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    Alias /awstats-icon/ /usr/share/awstats/icon/

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This is the .htaccess content (in /var/www/):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2   [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1  [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

And here's the error log output when requesting /home/asdf/ or /home/:

```
[Sat Jun 26 17:46:27 2010] [error] [client ..] File does not exist: /var/www/home
[Sat Jun 26 17:47:09 2010] [error] [client ..] File does not exist: /var/www/home
```

I'm not very good at regex and mod_rewrite, but it looks like the URL isn't rewritten at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have **mod_rewrite** enabled:

As root:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then, restart Apache2, as root:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: head -> keyboard

Comment: Haha, you're not alone. For one project a few years ago, I spent two hours trying to debug this sort of thing only to realize I didn't have mod_rewrite enabled. It's good for us to have humbling experiences like this every now and again. :)

Answer (score 2):

In  `<Directory /var/www/>` the directive `AllowOverride None` prevent the htaccess file to be used. You must at lease change it to `AllowOverride FileInfo`

Comment: Just changed it for both / and /var/www/, doesn't make a difference, error log still looks the same.